# Fading a ImageView

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I am trying to set an `ImageView` alpha. I am trying to make it compatible with api 14 so I have to use `.setAlpha()`

Anyway the issue is simple I want it to fade in a viewable fashion but the thread i have doesn't allow the UI to update. I need to run it on the UI Thread but I need to have the thread pause for a bit so the user can see the fading...

Right now there is no visiable fading and it just skips with the below code. I just need a way to make it fade and have it update on UI thread.

***need way to update UI thread and change alpha with pausing so user can see alpha changes

```
public void onFadeClick(View view) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
                try {
                    img.setAlpha(i);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    img.setAlpha(i);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to have the ui thread update the changes to alpha

Answer (score 0):

Simply do that through XML

Create `fade.xml` in `res/anim`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:repeat="reverse" //for playing back again.
    android:repeatCount="0" // for playing infinitely
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

Then in you code

```
Animation anim = Animation.loadAnimation(R.anim.fade);
youImageView.startAnimation(anim);
```